# How to compare and count each value of element with condition in mongoDB pipeline after unwinding?

Tags: mongodb, rockmongo

This is my command I ran in tools->command

```
{
aggregate : "hashtags",       
pipeline:

[

{$unwind:"$time"},
{$match:{"$time":{$gte:NumberInt(1450854385), $lte:NumberInt(1450854385)}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$word","count":{$sum:1}}}
]

}
```

which gave us this result

```
Response from server:
{
   "result": [
     {
       "_id": "dear",
       "count": NumberInt(1) 
    },
     {
       "_id": "ghost",
       "count": NumberInt(1) 
    },
     {
       "_id": "rat",
       "count": NumberInt(1) 
    },
     {
       "_id": "police",
       "count": NumberInt(1) 
    },
     {
       "_id": "bugs",
       "count": NumberInt(3) 
    },
     {
       "_id": "dog",
       "count": NumberInt(2) 
    },
     {
       "_id": "batman",
       "count": NumberInt(9) 
    },
     {
       "_id": "ear",
       "count": NumberInt(1) 
    } 
  ],
   "ok": 1 
}
```

The documents are in collection 'hashtags'
The documents inserted are as shown below
1.

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("567a483bf0058ed6755ab3de"),
   "hash_count": NumberInt(1),
   "msgids": [
     "1583" 
  ],
   "time": [
     NumberInt(1450854385) 
  ],
   "word": "ghost" 
}
```

2.

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5679485ff0058ed6755ab3dd"),
   "hash_count": NumberInt(1),
   "msgids": [
     "1563" 
  ],
   "time": [
     NumberInt(1450788886) 
  ],
   "word": "dear" 
}
```

3.

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("567941aaf0058ed6755ab3dc"),
   "hash_count": NumberInt(9),
   "msgids": [
     "1555",
     "1556",
     "1557",
     "1558",
     "1559",
     "1561",
     "1562",
     "1584",
     "1585" 
  ],
   "time": [
     NumberInt(1450787170),
     NumberInt(1450787292),
     NumberInt(1450787307),
     NumberInt(1450787333),
     NumberInt(1450787354),
     NumberInt(1450787526),
     NumberInt(1450787615),
     NumberInt(1450855148),
     NumberInt(1450855155) 
  ],
   "word": "batman" 
}
```

4.

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("567939cdf0058ed6755ab3d9"),
   "hash_count": NumberInt(3),
   "msgids": [
     "1551",
     "1552",
     "1586" 
  ],
   "time": [
     NumberInt(1450785157),
     NumberInt(1450785194),
     NumberInt(1450856188) 
  ],
   "word": "bugs" 
}
```

So I want to count the number of values in the field 'time' which comes in between two limits

such as this

```
foreach word
{
foreach time
{
if((a<time)&&(time<b))
word[count]++
}
}
```

but my query is just giving output of the total size of array 'time'.

What is the correct query?

for eg

```
if lower bound is 1450787615  and upper bound is  1450855155
```

there are 3 values in 'time'. for word 'batman'

```
The answer should be
{
           "_id": "batman",
           "count": NumberInt(3) 
        },
```

for batman.Thank you.

Comment: According to your range `1450787615 > 1450855155 -> false`

Comment: Thank you.. sorry I misplaced the upper bound with lower bound  .Is it ok now?

Comment: Should be alright now, check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.hashtags.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "time": {
                "$gte": 1450787615, "$lte": 1450855155  
            }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$time" },
    {
        "$match": {
            "time": {
                "$gte": 1450787615, "$lte": 1450855155  
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$word",
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

For the given sample documents, this will yield:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "batman",
            "count" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "dear",
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "ghost",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```